# android material design issue

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

i am trying to solve a issue for last 1 week. i am not sure what is wrong with the code.
i am trying to use this library https://github.com/rudsonlive/NavigationDrawer-MaterialDesign

I can able to compile and run the code

the issue is ,there is big difference in the display[image: first screen shot was take from my working code and second one i downloaded from play store.] quality

clearly we can notice the font is completely not matching.

please help me to resolve this.

Comment: What's the resolution on the testing device?

Comment: 5.5-inch Triluminos display sports a resolution of 720 x 1280 pixels, and this results in a mediocre pixel density of 267 ppi. I took both the screen shot using the same device. i guess both should look same . thanks @DDsix

Comment: No problem. You cannot expect the layout to look exactly the same on every device. This is (in my opinion) one of the biggest issues when developing Android Apps. Just try and test it on as much screens as you can. Use lots of emulators as well (I use Genymotion). Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Android Design Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) to achieve this.

It's quite easier and will surely fix your problem.

Check this official sample to learn how to use this:

https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I was about to post that link the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Omg i cannot believe it. the actual problem with me is eclipse.
I use android design support library and all other needed libraries.
i only can manage to run the project but when i imported the project using android studio everything is working fine without any additional work.
dam it.

any one tired with eclipse ?